# Changing multiple ROW values with in a single column, Followed but a filtering process

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, filtering, openpyxl

So my goal here is to filter for 2 service code(there will be hundreds in a single column) but in this case I need "4" and "CO4" that is the letter o capitalized not the number zero. FYI

Issues/Goals:

1. 4 and CO4 have a space in them like CO4(space) this varies as in some may not have the space. Humans..am I right? lol
2. Filtering in an addition column called 'Is Void' for False values with the above two service codes.* this is where I believe my issue is
   2a) this is because I lose a lot of data about 1700 rows with that code I will show in a bit.

**Sample Data base:**
[image]

My code: This has everything imported and data base in open too.

```py
dfRTR = dfRTR[["Zone Name", "End Time", "Is Void", "Ticket Notes", "Service Code", "Unit Count", "Disposal Monitor Name", "Addr No","Addr St", "Ticket Number"]]   #Columns I will use

dfRTR.replace("CO4 ","CO4") #Takes out (space) in CO4

dfRTR.replace("4 ", "4") #Takes out (space) in 4

filt = dfRTR[(dfRTR['Is Void'] == False) & (dfRTR["Service Code"].isin(["CO4 ", "4"]))]    #my problem child.
```

If I take this code out I have all my data, but with it only about 700-800 Rows which is supposed to be around 1500-2000k Rows in the column "Is Void".

I have only been coding for about two months, not knowing how to replace two values at once in the same column, is another topic. I am trying to automate my whole audit which can take 4hrs to 2-3days depending on the project. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

So, if i manual make my exccel all text then run this code:

```
dfRTR['Service Code'] = dfRTR['Service Code'].str.replace(r'\W', "")
filt = dfRTR[(dfRTR['Is Void'] != True) & dfRTR["Service 
Code"].isin(["CO4","4"])]

filt.to_excel('VecTest.xlsx')
```

And I can return all my data I need filtered. Only down side is that my date will have text formatting. I will try to automate one column in this case *'Service Code'* to be text then run it again.

Edit part 2: Making the above file in a CVS mas the filtering process way easier. Problem is converting it back to an excel. Excel formulas have an issue with simple formula like =A1=B1 if both cells A1 and B1 have a value of 1 they will not match. CVS pulls away all the extra "Formatting" but in the Excel VBA code I use to format it make the cell give off this warning, even though the data being pulled is from CVS format.

VBA code makes the values appear with the excel warning:
"The number in this cell is formatted as a text or preceded with an apostrophe"

Conclusion:
I would need to make all my check using python before using CVS formatting.

Comment: It has some thing to do with the "4" value. I noticed in my excel doc it has a warning that says "The number in this cell is formatted as a text or preceded with an apostrophe"
here is an example to work with if need. :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eSh6qhDeuSCIn_pUC2FyGVkbYrUn-vU1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My solution is a function but it does not need to be:

```
def getRTRVecCols(dfRTR):
# this is majority of special chars that may be in columns cells
    spec_chars = ["!", '"', "#", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", 
                  "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", ";", "<",
                  "=", ">", "?", "@", "[", "\\", "]", "^", "_",
                  "`", "{", "|", "}", "~", "–"]

# this forloop will remove all those special chars for a specific column
    for char in spec_chars: 
        dfRTR["Service Code"] = dfRTR["Service Code"].str.replace(char, ' ')

#with the above we may get white spaces. This is how to remove those
    dfRTR["Service Code"] = dfRTR["Service Code"].str.split().str.join(" ")

# take in multiple values for in one column to filter for (specific for me)
    codes = ["CO4", "4"]

#filtering our data set with multiple conditions. 2 conditions is in the same single column and another condition in a differnt column
   dfRTR = dfRTR[(dfRTR["Is Void"] != True) & (dfRTR["Service Code"].isin(codes))] 

#saves to a excel file
    dfRTR.to_excel('RTR Vec Cols.xlsx')

#my function call
getRTRVecCols(dfRTR)
```

Now I Do get this warning, which I am still to noob in python to understand yet. But is next on my list to fix. But it works perfect for now*

```
FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a 

future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will*not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
  dfRTR["Service Code"] = dfRTR["Service Code"].str.replace(char, ' ')
```

Comment: I noticed for my data. when I use df.loc[] if i pull up the data i need it does not count all the unit counts with it. example if the .loc[] has a unit count of 5 it will only show 1. due to each unit count would be on different rows. So i changed my index to be the ID and it shows all unit counts and rows that go with that particular ID

Comment: by adding regex=True in my replace() code it will eliminate the error message. Learn more here:
[What’s new in 1.2.0 (December 26, 2020)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#deprecationse)